# OpenCL syntax highlighting in CLion

Tags: opencl, syntax-highlighting, clion

Does anyone have a solution for syntax highlighting of OpenCL code for CLion?
I am placing the OpenCL source code in a file with the extension .cl and would like to have syntax highlighting for such files.

Answer (score 0):

In CLion you can add `.cl` files as [custom file types](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/creating-and-registering-file-types.html) and manually provide the list of OpenCL C keywords for syntax highlighting.

There is an alternative to loading the OpenCL C code from a `.cl` file at runtime: Embedding it right within C++, such as used in this [OpenCL-Wrapper](https://github.com/ProjectPhysX/OpenCL-Wrapper). While naive `string` literals would destroy syntax highlighting, there is a way to retain syntax highlighting with the

```c
#define R(...) std::string(" "#__VA_ARGS__" ")
```

stringification macro and by using [`#define`s for all the OpenCL C functions and keywords](https://github.com/ProjectPhysX/OpenCL-Wrapper/blob/master/src/kernel.hpp).